# how to use select and extract date into month and year from timestamp in sequelize ORM?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, aggregation

I have this query in sql:

```
select to_char (created_at,'Mon') as month,
extract (year from created_at) as year,
id_activity as activity
from event
group by 1, 2, 3
```

i tried something simple at first, like this to help my understading:
`model.findAll({attributes: [[ sequelize.fn('extract(year)', sequelize.col('created_at')), 'data']] })`

but it does not work.

i'm using postgresDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows -

```
model.findAll({attributes: [[ sequelize.fn('YEAR', sequelize.col('created_at')), 'data']] })
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: function year(timestamp with time zone) does not exist